# Two small changes have speeded-up this code by 20%; is it compiler specific as I cannot understand the increased speed?

Tags: arrays, c, performance

I have been experimenting speeding up code. By converting a 2-dimensional array to a 1-dimensional array, and removing two variables, I cannot understand the substantial difference, especially as the new code uses multiplication within a loop. Most things I have read say that 1 and 2 dimensional arrays make no difference to the processing speed.
The compiler is Apple Clang 11.0.0.(I use pointers because I find it makes a speed difference although I have been advised against it).

Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;

int main(void) {

    int exp, nlen;
    printf("Enter power: ");
    scanf("%d", &exp);

    if (exp < 0) {
        printf("Enter a positive number. \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int less2[2] = { 1, 2 };
    if (exp < 2) {
        printf("%d \n", less2[exp]);
        exit(0);
    }
    start = clock();
    int *pwr;
    nlen = ((exp - 1) / 3) + 2;
    printf("power = %d \n", nlen);

    pwr = (int*)calloc(nlen + 2, sizeof(int));
    if (pwr == NULL) {
        printf("pwr memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("memory allocated (calloc)\n");
    }


    const int lkt[10][10] = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
        { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
        { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
    };
    int a, b, c, d, m;
    int am[3] = { 8, 2, 4 };

    m = exp % 3;
    *(pwr + nlen - 2) = am[m];
    *(pwr + nlen - 1) = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nlen - 2; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nlen - 1; ++i) {
                a = *(pwr + i);
                b = *(pwr + i+1);
                *(pwr + i) = *(*(lkt + a) + b);
            }
        }
    }
    int z = 0;
    while (pwr[z] == 0) {
        ++z;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = z; i < nlen - 1; ++i) {
        printf("%d", *(pwr + i));
        ++count;
    }
    printf("\n\ncount = %d ", count);
    printf("\n");

    free (pwr);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nTime taken to run programme = %f ", cpu_time_used);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

New code - up to 20% faster:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;

int main(void) {

    int exp, nlen;
    printf("Enter power: ");
    scanf("%d", &exp);

    if (exp < 0) {
        printf("Enter a positive number. \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int less2[2] = { 1, 2 };

    if (exp < 2) {
        printf("%d \n", less2[exp]);
        exit(0);
    }
    start = clock();
    int *pwr;
    nlen = ((exp - 1) / 3) + 2;
    printf("power = %d \n", nlen);

    pwr = (int*)calloc(nlen+2, sizeof(int));

    if (pwr == NULL) {
        printf("pwr memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("memory allocated (calloc)\n");
    }
const int lkt[100] = {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9};

    int a, b, c, d, m;
    int am[3] = { 8, 2, 4 };

    m = exp % 3;
    *(pwr + nlen - 2) = am[m];
    *(pwr + nlen - 1) = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nlen - 2; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nlen - 1; ++i) {
                *(pwr + i) = *(lkt + (*(pwr + i) * 10) + *(pwr + i + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    int z = 0;
    while (pwr[z] == 0) {
        ++z;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = z; i < nlen - 1; ++i) {
        printf("%d", *(pwr + i));
        ++count;
    }
    printf("\n\ncount = %d ", count);
    printf("\n");

    free (pwr);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nTime taken to run programme = %f ", cpu_time_used);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first code is missing `start = clock();` so it's also timing the user's entry response (`clock()` returns a count since the start of execution). And what time period was it? Aim for at least one second.

Comment: @Weather Vane - Thank you for pointing that out. I have now added it but it has made no difference to the speed.

Comment: I presume you mean that your tests included it. It *must* make a difference, consider the user thinking about their response to `printf("Enter power: "); scanf("%d", &exp);` for several seconds before tapping <Enter>. Anyway, what value did you enter?

Comment: Be aware that if `p` is a pointer and `i` is an integer then `*(p + i)` is 100% equivalent to `p[i]`.  You use the former form all over, but the latter is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `clock()` measures the CPU time, so while you are correct about only timing relevant parts of the code, the timing should not include the wait time for user response.

Comment: @Weather Vane -  I entered 100,000 although last night when I was cooking dinner I entered 1,000,000.

Comment: @chqrlie - Thank you for editing my code. I really must take your advice and improve my formatting.

Comment: Thank you, my compilations results in about 10 and 12 seconds execution time with 100000, but they do include a lot of terminal output (accounting for about 2 seconds).

Comment: @chqrlie yes, I am used to MS non-standard `clock()` which measures wall time.

Comment: @John Bollinger - I have been told about my use of pointers but when I first started learning C I practised for ages to understand them so now they feel natural to me.

Comment: Unrelated: `Enter a positive number.` and then `if (exp < 2)` seems to allow all numbers from `INT_MIN` up to `1` (inclusive). That's a pretty big "hole" in the validation of the entered number. Also, is `0` positive? Perhaps it should say `"Enter a non-negative number:"`  and validate that it is.

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: @IanStewart, I am glad you have developed an affinity for pointers.  That will be useful to you.  But if you actually find the `*(p + i)` form easier to read or write than `p[i]` then I daresay you are unique in the world.  And if you want other people (us, or the other present or future programmers on your team) to be able to read your code easily then you should use the `p[i]` form.

Comment: Thanks John Bollinger, I think it's years of studying music counterpoint from an early age, plus my father taught me how to crack cyphers when I was nine.

Comment: Having built the two versions of your code with gcc at optimization at level `-O2`, I find no significant difference in their run times.  If one is any faster than the other, then the difference is much less than the run-to-run variation of either one of them alone.

Comment: @n. m. will see y'all on Reddit - I use the standard Macos Clang: cc     code.c   -o code

Comment: @IanStewart, performance testing unoptimized binaries is worse than useless.  Add `-O2` or `-O3` to your compilation command, and also pay attention to the issues chqrlie raises in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76642964/2402272).

Comment: Code like `*(pwr + i) = *(lkt + (*(pwr + i) * 10) + *(pwr + i + 1));` is unreadable to most of us. Do not write code like that, ever. Do use the subscript operator. It does not make your code run slow. Compiling without optimisations enabled makes your code run slow.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: You are, of course, correct. I went back to the original code with a 2-D array and used lkt[a][b] instead of pointers and compared versions - they are basically the same. I compiled with Clang -O3, which was a fraction faster than gcc -O3.

Comment: @IanStewart, I get the feeling that you may not be fully grasping what I'm trying to tell you.  The indexing operator (`[]`) is a binary operator on one pointer (not array) and one integer.  `x[y]` is **defined** to mean `*((x) + (y))`, and it follows that `y[x]` is also equivalent.  You are using pointers either way, and the difference between the two forms is purely stylistic.  When one of the expressions `x`, `y` designates an array, the automatic conversion of that array to a pointer (which is free) factors in.

Comment: Sorry John, it was careless use of terminology in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your timings are not reliable: you should avoid including any terminal output, a fortiori, any terminal input in the range of code you time.  Move the initial call to `clock()` after the `printf("memory allocated (calloc)\n")` and the second call before writing the result to the terminal.

Modified this way, the difference in timings for 100000 falls below 0.5% (**1.072660 sec** and **1.067578 sec** on my macbook), below the margin of error for such measurements.

If you get a significant difference, this may be caused by compilation options: if you disable optimisations, the code might be indeed less efficient for one or the other versions, but with optimisations enabled, give the fixed size of the 2D and 1D array, the code generated should be very similar and have equivalent performance.

To accelerate this program, you should avoid handing all digits for all operations, and you could handle 9 digits at a time with a right to left approach similar to high school arithmetics.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    clock_t start, end;
    int exp;

    printf("Enter power: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &exp) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (exp < 0) {
        printf("Enter a positive number. \n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (exp < 31) {
        printf("%d\n", 1 << exp);
        return 0;
    }
    // store 9 decimal digits in each array element
    int nlen = exp / 27 + 3;

    int *pwr = (int *)calloc(nlen, sizeof(int));
    if (pwr == NULL) {
        printf("memory allocation error.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("memory allocated (%d slots)\n", nlen);

    start = clock();

    int top = 0;
    pwr[top] = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < exp; k++) {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
            int tmp = pwr[i] + pwr[i] + carry;
            carry = tmp >= 1000000000;
            pwr[i] = tmp - carry * 1000000000;
        }
        if (carry) {
            pwr[++top] = carry;
        }
    }

    end = clock();

    int count = printf("%d", pwr[top]);
    for (int i = top; i --> 0;) {
        count += printf("%09d", pwr[i]);
    }
    printf("\ncount = %d\n", count);

    free (pwr);

    double cpu_time_used = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTime taken to run program = %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

It computes 2<sup>100000</sup> accurately in 0.250 sec on my M2 macbook air.

Comment: Ref: brushing up on Latin [a fortiori](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20fortiori)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions which I have put into practise. However I can't get anywhere near you speeds. On a 2013 iMac it takes 188 seconds to run - 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5. On a 2017 MacBook Pro it takes 250 seconds.

Comment: Many thanks Chqrlie, I will study your code in great detail. On our iMac 2^100000 takes 0.164281 seconds. I compiled it  with clang -O3.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you have used

```
a = *(pwr + i); 
b = *(pwr + i+1);
*(pwr + i) = *(*(lkt + a) + b);
```

but in the second code you have used a single expression

```
*(pwr + i) = *(lkt + (*(pwr + i) * 10) + *(pwr + i + 1));
```

After I changed the first one to the more similar single expression

```
*(pwr + i) = *(*(lkt + *(pwr + i)) + *(pwr + i+1));
```

the two codes take about the same time. Perhaps the results depend on compiler optimisation settings.

Comment: The two codes take the same time for me even without making that modification.  Though it may make a difference that I compiled both with optimization enabled.  And I note that optimization made a *huge* difference in the run times for both versions -- a runtime reduction of about 80% relative to no optimization.